# How to save battery while playing Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon GO uses an insane amount of battery, I have to constantly carry my battery bank around.

I've tried the battery saver mode but it does not seem to have any impact.

What can I do to improve my battery life while playing Pokemon GO?

Comment: The battery saving mode just makes the screen black when you turn your phone upside-down, it has no other effect.

Answer (score 1):

***Offline Maps***

One of the biggest ways to save on battery consumption (and data usage too) is to use offline maps.

This can be done by downloading the Google Maps app, going into the settings and selecting "offline maps".

Due to Pokemon Go using the Google Maps API, with this option selected, Pokemon Go will use the map you have previously downloaded in the Google Maps app instead of streaming it as you move around.

***General Power Saving***

Close as many background apps as you can.

Disable sound (you can also disable vibration but then you will need to constantly be looking at your phone which will invalidate the power saving mode in the game.).

Lower the brightness of the screen and enable black and white mode (android).

Disable bluetooth and wi-fi.

***Other***

There is a power saving option in Pokemon GO settings.

Disable the AR mode when catching Pokemon or fighting in gyms.

Comment: The Google maps trick was debunked unfortunately, the Pokemon Go app, while using Google maps code for its Geo, doesn't have access to the data downloaded for offline maps by the Google Maps app

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I can see so many people who have tested it and have noticed a difference, both online and friends. Where is it debunked?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I would also like a source

Comment: Note that anything to due with the screen color (black screen, black and white mode) only has an effect if your phone has an AMOLED screen. Lowering the screen's general brightness is still useful though as this affects the power output of the backlight. AMOLED screens do not have backlights.